# Android change ActionBar text color

Tags: java, android

I'm using Appcompat in the App.

How can I change the text color of the ActionBar?
I've tried a personalized theme but it doesn't work

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">        
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColor">#000080</item>
</style>
```

Comment: is "AppTheme" your current theme in the manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Since the Toolbar is like any other view, you can change the way you want your text to look like particularly the title text:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/custom_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorRed"
            android:text="@string/title_activity_mainr"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

This should help change the text color.

In fact, you can change the position of the title text as you wish!

Happy coding!

Comment: You can add a textview element dynamically to your ToolBar

Comment: with this type of solution i must change all the activity of the app, adding a Toolbar without using the Actionbar already inserted by Android Studio

Comment: Why do you want to add toolbar dynamically?

Comment: Not dinamically, but with the xml file.

Comment: Yeah but that is easy; just make sure to do what I did there for reach activity you need; that will be easier

Comment: The problem is how to remove the Toolbar in the activity since it's not in the xml file

Comment: I feel like I can help you more through gmail here if you are okay! We need to modify your styles.xml file to remove the toolbar and then fix that issue by adding a toolbar of our own

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any problem to do this alone if it's the only way to resolve the problem, i didn't want to change because of my lazyness